# C get compilation options inside the code

Tags: c, compilation, dynamic-compilation

I'm writing a GUI to an application, but the main developer wants to set in Makefile if the GUI get or not compiled with the rest. I'm putting all the GTK+ code in a separated file, but in the main file I need to test if the application is being compiled with the GUI or not, so how I can test this?

E.g:

```
if(COMPILED_WITH_GTK)
    #include "my_gtk_stuffs.h"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `COMPILED_WITH_GTK` is an argument to the compiler command in the Makefile (in the form of `-DCOMPILED_WITH_GTK`) you use a preprocessor directive.

```
#ifdef COMPILED_WITH_GTK
#include "my_gtk_stuffs.h"
#endif
```

This tells the preprocessor to only process the `#include` statement if `COMPILED_WITH_GTK` is defined.

Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Conditional_compilation), as well.

Comment: @user1129682 Thanks for pointing that out. You might be able to guess what I have been programming in lately due to that.